# Loading assembly with dependencies in AppDomain trouble

Tags: c#, .net-assembly, appdomain

I have some problem when trying to load assembly in new AppDomain.
My "working" assembly is not loading, but instead it, loads assembly from references.
What is wrong in my code?

[image]

```
    using Autofac;
    using System;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Reflection;
    using System.Security;
    using System.Security.Permissions;
    using System.Security.Policy;
    using System.Timers;
    using Topshelf;
    using Topshelf.Autofac;
    using Vero.TaskScheduler.Core.Contracts;

    namespace Vero.TaskScheduler.Host {
        class Program {
            static void Main(string[] args) {
                AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve;
                AppDomainSetup domaininfo = new AppDomainSetup();
                domaininfo.ApplicationBase = System.Environment.CurrentDirectory;
                Evidence adevidence = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Evidence;
                AppDomain domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("MyDomain", adevidence, domaininfo);

                domain.Load(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("f:\\Autofac.dll"));
                domain.Load(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("f:\\linq2db.dll"));
                domain.Load(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("f:\\Quartz.dll"));
                domain.Load(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("f:\\Vero.TaskScheduler.Core.dll"));
                domain.Load(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("f:\\Vero.TaskScheduler.TestRefLib.dll"));
                domain.Load(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("f:\\Vero.TaskScheduler.TestTask.dll"));
                domain.Load(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("f:\\Vero.TaskScheduler.TestTask.dll"));


                var i = domain.GetAssemblies();                
                return;
       }
}
```

P.S. Assembly "Vero.TaskScheduler.TestTask.dll" load succesful when it not refered to "Vero.TaskScheduler.TestRefLib.dll", else it's not loaded

Comment: The 'assembly' tag has to do with assembly language (asm), not .Net assemblies.

Comment: Sorry , I'm newbie on StackOverflow site :-)

Comment: We all were at one time.  I'm just mentioning so you can edit your question to direct it to the right people.

Comment: Thank you, I changed tags set

Comment: Please add your sample code directly to the post, and not with an image, the image could be seen as an additional info, but having the code inside the post as text is lots better

Comment: Done! Thank you!

Comment: Is there a reason why you have the dlls you wish to load referenced in your project? Or rather, why do you want to load them manually when you can reference them?

Comment: Yes, there is reason . I need dynamicaly execute code, from different dlls by schedule. This is just sample

Comment: So, you are creating a plugin based system? Then you should keep interfaces and executions in seperate libraries, reference the dlls that contain the interfaces and load the dlls that contain the implementation

Comment: Yes, like a plugin based system. Interfaces are keeping in Vero.TaskScheduler.Core.dll, and this assembly loads also like all need dlls

Comment: That would be hard to implement, as you cannot really call your tasks, if it is part of your dynamic loading process (you cannot really reference a type used in your core library that you want to load and execute except for `dynamic` types) I mean, it would be easier to load the types by interface, and then call the methods on those interfaces, so therefor, reference the interface definition, but load the execution dll seperately

Comment: I want use it like this. But need assembly not loaded.
                `IWork m_work = domain.GetAssemblies()
                .First(x => x.FullName.Contains("TestTask"))
                .GetTypes()
                .Where(x => typeof(IWork).IsAssignableFrom(x))
                .Select(x => (IWork)Activator.CreateInstance(x))
                .First();
            m_work.Execute();`

Comment: And where is your `IWork` defined? It needs to be known before you can use it

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem. Add AssemblyResolve event handle like this:

```
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve;
```

And handler

```
    private static System.Reflection.Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args) {
         return Assembly.LoadFile($"f:\\{args.Name.Split(',')[0]}.dll");
    }
```

Thanks all!!!